# Batch to delete all except certain extensions recursively

Tags: batch-file, recursion

I need to delete content of a folder recursively except specific extensions
to prevent it from being overflowed with non-office files.

I tried this:

```
@echo off
SET ROOTDIR=E:\Testdel\
for /f %%F in ('dir %ROOTDIR% /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".xls .xlt .xlm .xlsx .xlsm .xltx .xltm .ppt .pot .pps .pptx .pptm .potx .ppam .ppsx .sldx .sldm .pdf .xls .doc .dot .docx. .html .docm .dotb .docb .tiff .jpg .png .cdr .cpt .psd"') do del "%%F"
```

But it outputs the error:

> Could Not Find C:\Users\username\New

Any idea why?

Comment: If you set ROOTDIR to `E:\Testdel\`, how could the error message tell that `C:\Users\username\New` is not found? Does folder or file `New` actual exists? Or is that name split at a space? I would guess that this code does not handle spaces in name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the default delimiter is `delim=<tab><space>` so it splits file names by spaces. Also, if you want to recursively delete the files then you have to specify the `/s` flag for `dir`. Try this:

```
@echo off
set ROOTDIR=E:\Testdel\
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir %ROOTDIR% /s /b /a-d ^|findstr /vile ".xls .xlt .xlm .xlsx .xlsm .xltx .xltm .ppt .pot .pps .pptx .pptm .potx .ppam .ppsx .sldx .sldm .pdf .xls .doc .dot .docx .html .docm .dotb .docb .tiff .jpg .png .cdr .cpt .psd"') do del "%%F"
```

Note:
[Wikibooks - Windows Batch Scripting: Switches](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Switches) mentions that *generally*, switches cannot be accumulated behind a single slash. It also mentions that the `findstr` command is an **exception** and allows `/v /i /l /e` to be combined into `/vile` as a shortcut. This also means that order here doesn't matter and `/vile` = `/live` = any other ordering (this was pointed out by [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi)). There may be other commands that support this, however since they are exceptions, its a good idea to separate the switches as this would work in all cases and would cause less confusion.

Comment: Hi.. this solution doesnt work on files with non-roman characters such as japanese or chinese.. what if i want to add another rule del size bigger than 100MB?

Comment: Hello, what would be the change to have it as variable root folder(so you could put it in any kind of folder) and run it from that folder recursively? Thank you